# How to find out which call to a static library is responsible for triggering an error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

When running my code I notice the following error in my debugging console:

> The Async request has been failed due to following error : Error
>   Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=6 "Unable to start HTTP
>   connection" UserInfo=0xb1b5d90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to start
>   HTTP connection}

This error is no where in the code, so it must be coming from one of the static library, because I can find it in the final binary via:

```
strings MyApp | grep "Async request"
```

How do I find out which call to a static library or which lib is responsible for triggering this?

Comment: Do the same grep over the individual library files before linking?